# EC2 Ubuntu instance npm is not installing any package

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, npm-install

I have an error installing any package, even if I run `sudo npm i -g npm` I get the same error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-1032-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I don't know where to start for debugging, I thought I have a problem with my internet but I can ping google.com from my EC2 Instance, even when I ping `104.16.16.35` I get response packets.

**EC2 Instance outbound rules:**
[image]

**Curl response for `curl -I 104.16.27.35:443`**

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 104.16.27.35 port 443: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Checking with ping isn't enough since ping works at ICMP but it's possible that there is security rule blocking TCP:443 to the listed address.  See if you can connect to 104.16.16.35:443 (e.g., using curl or wget) -- and double-check the outbound security rules for that EC2 instance.

Comment: @peekay Terribly sorry for the late response, I updated the question body with the requested info

Comment: You should open outbound port 443 in the security rules so that npm can install the packages

Comment: @JuanScolari NICE! thank you so much, please add this to the answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` downloads the packages it will install via `https`, so you should add port `443` to the outbound rules in your security group configuration.